# Code runs in simulation but not on chip

Tags: atmega, glcd

I am trying to interface JHD12864E graphic LCD with an ATmega32 controller. I simulated it in proteus using the LGM12641BS1R model. Both are KS0108 compatible so I thought it should work. I have written some code using the procyon avr library. The only change I did was to modify the code for a active high RST signal (in place of an active low signal as on LGM12641). For that I changed the function glcdreset and added a not in the if condition. Also in the proteus model I added a not gate primitive before the RST signal. So now I guess my model and the actual chip are compatible. And it works too, in simulation. But when I burn it on the ATmega32 chip I do not get anything except the LED backlight. I have double checked the wires and they are in order. What else may be the problem?

Comment: Probably a simulator problem. Have you asked Proteus about it?

Comment: how do I ask proteus? Also, since the lcd is compatible with the ks0108 controller, it should work.

Comment: I think the issue is common ground or common anode problem. Check it up.

Comment: @sandundhammika if I connect the LCD all the dots are active as if its high contrast. So I guess common ground or common anode problem is not there.

Comment: @Rick_2047 *All* dots active? Do you have contrast control working yet?

Comment: Tried that, no luck. The pot does not have any effect at all

Answer (score 1):

The same problem was with me with 16x2 character LCD.
I recognized that Proteus runs the code even without 'pot' connected to Vo pin. Try connecting the 10k pot to Vo pin and calibrate to provide nearly ground potential...